# how to export the observed and expected counts of chi square test to a table

Tags: r

I am trying to export the results of a chi square test to a table with the observed and expected counts. I am getting this result with both of the observed values in the cells along with the expected value, instead of a single observed value

```
test =table(mtcars$am, mtcars$carb)
test =as.data.frame.matrix(table(mtcars$am, mtcars$carb))
Xsq <- chisq.test(test)

test2 <-test  
test2[] <- paste(test, paste0("(", round(Xsq$expected),")"))
```

I would like for the output to look like this in each cell:

Observed (Expected)  Observed (Expected)  Observed (Expected)  Observed (Expected)

Observed (Expected)  Observed (Expected)  Observed (Expected)  Observed (Expected)

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```r
x <- with(mtcars, table(am, carb))
test <- chisq.test(x)

res <- paste0(test$observed, " (", test$expected, ")")
res_table <- test$observed  # Cheap way to get the output structure
res_table[] <- res
res_table

# Output
   carb
am  1           2          3           4          6           8          
  0 3 (4.15625) 6 (5.9375) 3 (1.78125) 7 (5.9375) 0 (0.59375) 0 (0.59375)
  1 4 (2.84375) 4 (4.0625) 0 (1.21875) 3 (4.0625) 1 (0.40625) 1 (0.40625)
```